# Is there a way to stop a qmenu from being hidden when you click off of the menu

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMenu. I would like to keep the menu up when you click outside menu. Is this possible. I have tried overriding the `event`method but that does not work. I know how to keep the menu open when you click on an action (there are a few questions here about that) but I want to keep it up when you click outside the menu, clicking on an action should still close the menu. This should work when bringing up the menu via `popup` or `exec`. Is this possible using QMenu?

EDIT: showTearOffMenu is not what I want, I would like to keep these pop-up frameless

EDIT #2: Overriding closeEvent and ignoring it will keep the menu up but now it steals all clicks

```cpp
void MenuSubclass::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* e){
    e->ignore();
}
```

Comment: Try installEventFilter() and check and block any events trying to hide the menu.

Comment: @edin-m
What events would you say should be blocked? I have already tried it with `MouseButtonRelease` and `MouseButtonPress`. When I am clicking outside of the menu the events never get to them so I am wondering if it is possible that some other system is hiding (not sure if that is possible. I think it could be possible to jerry rig something using `aboutToHide` but that feels very wrong and bug prone

Comment: Calling showTearOffMenu() on your QMenu will give you a floating menu-dialog that doesn’t go away when you click on it or outside it

Comment: Jeremy Friesner , That works but is not what I want. We would prefer to keep it without the window frame.